# how to make particular part of string bold in React JS?

Tags: reactjs

I am building reactJs app. I am using textArea from react-spectrum/ prime. In this textArea , I need to show some text in bold letters.

I have tried something like this.

const data = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.'

I need to make "popularised in" in bold letters.

i have tried implementing style in textarea, also tried with the following function

```
function boldString(str, find){
        var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
        return str.replace(re, '<b>'+find+'</b>');
    }
```

but this doesn't worked.

If anyone knows the solution please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML as follows

```
function boldString(str, find){
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>'+find+'</b>');
}

var str = boldString('input string', 'find value')

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: str}}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem with solution in your question is that you are trying to insert DOM element trough string, and you can use that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop but that is a bit hacky and ad hoc.

You can try this out. This will cover any value that you want to bold:

```js
const data =
  "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

export default function App() {
  const boldPartOfText = (boldingText, targetText) => {
    if (!targetText) {
      return "";
    }
    const indexOfText = targetText.indexOf(boldingText);

    if (indexOfText === -1) {
      return targetText;
    }
    const endIndexOfText = indexOfText + boldingText.length;

    return (
      <>
        {`${targetText.slice(0, indexOfText)}`}
        <b>{targetText.slice(indexOfText, endIndexOfText)}</b>
        {targetText.slice(endIndexOfText)}
      </>
    );
  };
  return <div className="App">{boldPartOfText("Lorem ", data)}</div>;
}
```

I made codesandbox with working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-bolding-text-zlucy

Comment: if the text we want to bold is dynamic then also this method will work?

Comment: also , need to do bold text in textarea so that user can add their text if they want

Comment: I will modify this example to accept any text

Comment: As far as the text area bolding, you cannot do that natively, you need to use some of the custom WYSIWYG text areas. `<textarea>` does not provide that. https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

Comment: I am rendering text from another component and want to make some part of text bold also that text needs to show in text area.

Comment: Is there any way to change the value in string which is returing from the above example function, and that value we can use to show in textarea

Comment: Well, bolding anything in text area is impossible because Textarea does not have that. You can use some custom editor as i said above. https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

Answer (score 0):

By using "react-contenteditable" library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-contenteditable we can edit the content and if we want to bold particular text, we can do it by using html tags.

```
import React from 'react'
import ContentEditable from 'react-contenteditable'
 
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.contentEditable = React.createRef();
    this.state = {html: "<b>Hello <i>World</i></b>"};
  };
 
  handleChange = evt => {
    this.setState({html: evt.target.value});
  };
 
  render = () => {
    return <ContentEditable
              innerRef={this.contentEditable}
              html={this.state.html} // innerHTML of the editable div
              disabled={false}       // use true to disable editing
              onChange={this.handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
              tagName='article' // Use a custom HTML tag (uses a div by default)
            />
  };
};
```